# How to use the former value of a variable after the value has changed?

Tags: python

I wrote a code that is supposed to convert a number from base 10 to another base. This is the code, where n is the number to convert and l is the base to convert to:

```
def convert_from_base_10(n,l):
  import math
  counter = 0
  m=n
  z=0
  string = ""
  if n<2:
    return n
  else:
    while m>=l:
      m=m/l
      counter +=1
  while counter >= 0:
    z= math.floor(n/(l**counter))
    string = string + str(z)  
    n = n-z*(l**counter)
    counter = counter - 1
  return string
```

Because in the first else statement I change the value of the number I want to convert by dividing m by l, I had to assign m = n and use m instead of n. Is there a way to get around this and use only on variable?

Comment: When choosing variable names, it's a really good idea to avoid single letters, especially lowercase l, which looks almost exactly like the number 1 on a lot of people's screens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but I'm adding an answer as a workaround. Please take a look at the Math library from Python.

Please let me know if something like this might help:

```
log(x)/log(base)
```

> math.log(x[, base]) With one argument, return the natural logarithm of
>   x (to base e).
>
> With two arguments, return the logarithm of x to the given base,
>   calculated as log(x)/log(base).

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it you do not want to use the built in functions as NellMartinez pointed out I think adding another function might be what you are looking for to remove a variable from it.

```
def set_count(n, l):
    count = 0
    if n >= 2:
        while n >= l:
            n = n / l
            count += 1
    return count


def convert_from_base_10(n, l):
    string = ""

    counter = set_count(n, l)

    while counter >= 0:
        z = math.floor(n / (l ** counter))
        string = string + str(z)
        n = n - z * (l ** counter)
        counter = counter - 1
    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to use a dictionary or a list.

Instead of assigning `n` to `m`, and using two variables, you may choose to use a list `list_name = [n, n]`. Now you can keep list_name[0] as constant and vary list_name[1].

With dictionary, you may do something like `dict_name = {"original": n, "variable": n}`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rewrite your code like this (it is the same code just more readable and better formatted. Some names still remain for you to choose)

You should return always a coherent result if it is a string, always return a string

I don't see a problem in saving var content if you need it later.
Note that number is a local function parameter so you won't alter the original (which is actually an immutable also in your case) but you want to
change the local value a bit later, so it's ok to copy it to m.

There are other ways to do the conversion but I suppose you want to code the algorithm not a brief solution.

```
import math

def convert_base10_to(number, base):
    counter = 0
    m = number  # choose a proper name to m: what is m?
                # That will be the best name for m
    z = 0       # same for z
    result = ""
    if number < 2:
        return str(number)
    else:
        while m >= base:
            m = m / base
            counter += 1
    while counter >= 0:
        z = math.floor(number / (base ** counter))
        result = result + str(z)  
        number = number - z *(base ** counter)
        counter = counter - 1
    return result

print(convert_base10_to(7, 2))
```